# How to prettify symbols inside comments?

Tags: comment, symbols, prettify-symbols-mode

I'm using prettify-symbol mode together with [Pragmata Pro.el](https://github.com/fabrizioschiavi/pragmatapro/blob/master/emacs_snippets/pragmatapro-prettify-symbols-v0.827.el).
Ligatures work perfectly fine in the source code but for some reason with comments they don't. I think I'm missing something since it's not the first time I've fought with ligatures in Emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When symbols are composed with `prettify-symbols-mode` is controlled by `prettify-symbols-compose-predicate`. By default this will only compose symbols if they are at a word boundary and not inside a comment or string. It checks the parser state with `syntax-ppss` to verify that the point is outside of a comment or string. We can change this to only check if we outside a string. That way it will compose symbols in comments as well.

The only part of this function we changed was to change `(nth 8 (syntax-ppss))` (which means in comment or string) to `(nth 3 (syntax-ppss))` (which means in string).

```
  (setq prettify-symbols-compose-predicate
        (defun my-prettify-symbols-default-compose-p (start end _match)
          "Same as `prettify-symbols-default-compose-p', except compose symbols in comments as well."
          (let* ((syntaxes-beg (if (memq (char-syntax (char-after start)) '(?w ?_))
                                   '(?w ?_) '(?. ?\\)))
                 (syntaxes-end (if (memq (char-syntax (char-before end)) '(?w ?_))
                                   '(?w ?_) '(?. ?\\))))
            (not (or (memq (char-syntax (or (char-before start) ?\s)) syntaxes-beg)
                     (memq (char-syntax (or (char-after end) ?\s)) syntaxes-end)
                     (nth 3 (syntax-ppss)))))))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm <3

Comment: It seems that indeed for emacs-lisp it works like a charm, but for other modes like `clojure-mode` it does not. Maybe you know why?

Comment: Maybe `prettify-symbols-compose-predicate` is buffer local. Can you check the value of it inside `closure-mode` and make sure that is it is pointing to our function?

Comment: Thank you one more time :D I just defined the function globally and now everything works as expected!