# Append Prettify Ignore Symbols

Tags: prettify-symbols-mode

Prettify seems to work well with languages like matlab or python by ignoring things like addition (+) or multiplication (*) when directly next to the symbol. I'd like to add things like underscore (_) to that ignore list, but I can't seem to find out where.

Python-mode seems to automatically do this, but it's not always active, so I imagine it must be stored in some kind of list. I imagine it has something to do with: [How to prettify symbols inside comments?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47706/how-to-prettify-symbols-inside-comments), but I can't seem to figure it out.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol boundaries are controlled through the function registered at the variable `prettify-symbols-compose-predicate`.

That function is `prettify-symbols-default-compose-p` by default. If that function returns non-nil the symbol that starts at `START`, ends at `END`, and has match-string `MATCH` is accepted for prettification.

Citation from `prog-mode.el`:

```el
(defun prettify-symbols-default-compose-p (start end _match)
  "Return true iff the symbol MATCH should be composed.
The symbol starts at position START and ends at position END.
This is the default for `prettify-symbols-compose-predicate'
which is suitable for most programming languages such as C or Lisp."
  ;; Check that the chars should really be composed into a symbol.
  (let* ((syntaxes-beg (if (memq (char-syntax (char-after start)) '(?w ?_))
                           '(?w ?_) '(?. ?\\)))
         (syntaxes-end (if (memq (char-syntax (char-before end)) '(?w ?_))
                           '(?w ?_) '(?. ?\\))))
    (not (or (memq (char-syntax (or (char-before start) ?\s)) syntaxes-beg)
             (memq (char-syntax (or (char-after end) ?\s)) syntaxes-end)
             (nth 8 (syntax-ppss))))))
```

As one sees the predicate is syntax controlled. If the syntax at the beginning of the symbol is "word" or "symbol" then the character before may **not** be of syntax "word" or "symbol". Futhermore the match may not be within a comment or string.

I would recommend to **not** change the syntax of any characters like `_`. That has too many side-effects since the syntax-table is used in many other places.

You can roll your own predicate for `prettify-symbols-compose-predicate`.

For an instance you could additionally explicitly allow `_` before `start` and after `end`.

```el
(defun my-prettify-symbols-compose-p (start end _match)
  "Return true iff the symbol MATCH should be composed.
The symbol starts at position START and ends at position END.
This is the default for `prettify-symbols-compose-predicate'
which is suitable for most programming languages such as C or Lisp."
  ;; Check that the chars should really be composed into a symbol.
  (let* ((syntaxes-beg (if (memq (char-syntax (char-after start)) '(?w ?_))
                           '(?w ?_) '(?. ?\\)))
         (syntaxes-end (if (memq (char-syntax (char-before end)) '(?w ?_))
                           '(?w ?_) '(?. ?\\))))
    (not (or (and
               (null (memq (char-before start) '(?_)))
               (memq (char-syntax (or (char-before start) ?\s)) syntaxes-beg))
             (and
               (null (memq (char-after end) '(?_)))
               (memq (char-syntax (or (char-after end) ?\s)) syntaxes-end))
             (nth 8 (syntax-ppss))))))
```

Don't forget to register `my-prettify-symbols-compose-p` at `prettify-symbols-compose-predicate` within the hook of the major mode where it is required, i.e.:

```el
(add-hook 'my-major-mode-hook (lambda ()
                                 (setq prettify-symbols-compose-predicate #'my-prettify-symbols-compose-p)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I had trouble making heads or tails of some of that code and would most likely have broken something.