# Is there a package or functionality to alias some text into org-mode (not for export) and continuous editing?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a package or a feature in emacs that will let me use an alias for a slug of text?  The way I'd like to use it is to make an alias and everywhere in the text the alias is placed the **value** of the alias is shown instead of the name of the alias.  Possibly through some kind of markup.

I'd like to be able toggle editing between seeing the value and seeing the name.  Or it could behave a lot like `org-hide-emphasis-markers` does by hiding the extra markup but carrying out emphasis.

Perhaps this is also easy to construct an elisp function for that I'm just unaware of the right combination of features to use.

An example the plain text might look like this:

```
#+alias: ProductName "Super Toaster"

 * Features:
 The $ProductName has slots for 32 slices of bread.
```

The edited view would look like this (not just for/upon export):

```
 * Features:
 The Super Toaster has slots for 32 slices of bread.
```

When view in emacs the `$ProductName` would be `Super Toaster` but I could either edit the variable or the name in-place.

Comment: I am not aware of such functionality, but maybe you could use the answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/71453/26163)

Comment: Yeah, I gave the snippet in the reference a shot.  It worked well.  I'll just have to incorporate it a bit.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are several snippets mode in emacs that lets you create your own snippets. I use yas-mode.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25755)

Comment: Also this isn't a snippet.  A snippet replaces the text as permanent (give or take undo).  The original question is about having multiple views of the buffer in a sense.  Like `org-hide-emphasis-markers`.